# syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In Laravel 4.2, I am getting the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_PARSE)
syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ')'
```

This error happens in class Recommendation, which provides static function getRecommendations

```
class Recommendation extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'recommendations';

    public static function getRecommendations($userID) {
        $recommendations = DB::table('recommendations')
            ->join('sites', function($join) use ($user->id) {
                $join->on('sites.id', '=', 'recommendations.site_id');
                $join->on('sites.owner', '=', DB::raw($userID));
            })
            ->select('recommendations.id', 'recommendations.title', 'recommendations.body', 'recommendations.site_id', 'site.address')
            ->get();
        return $recommendations;
    }

}
```

on this line

```
->join('sites', function($join) use ($user->id) {
```

I cannot understand, what's wrong with the query..

Structure of **Recommendations** table is

```
id  int(10) unsigned Autoincrement   
title   varchar(255)     
body    text     
site_id int(10) unsigned     
created_at  timestamp [0000-00-00 00:00:00]  
updated_at  timestamp [0000-00-00 00:00:00]
```

and **Sites** table is

```
id  int(10) unsigned Автоматическое приращение   
sitename    varchar(255)     
address varchar(64)  
owner   int(10) unsigned     
created_at  timestamp [0000-00-00 00:00:00]  
updated_at  timestamp [0000-00-00 00:00:00]
```

Comment: What is your $user->id ? You are not using it anywhere. You only have $userID

Comment: that's what happens whan you start to panic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no variable `$user` available in function `getRecommendations()`, the function argument `$userID` is not used inside the function and the anonymous function uses `$userID`.

The only conclusion is that the line should read:

```
->join('sites', function($join) use ($userID) {
```

Comment: surely, such simple mistake... sorry for bothering

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a value with `use` it has to be a **local variable**.

Either assign it before:

```
$userId = $user->id;
$recommendations = DB::table('recommendations')
        ->join('sites', function($join) use ($userId) {
            $join->on('sites.id', '=', 'recommendations.site_id');
            $join->on('sites.owner', '=', DB::raw($userId));
        })
```

Or pass the whole `$user`:

```
->join('sites', function($join) use ($user) {
            $join->on('sites.id', '=', 'recommendations.site_id');
            $join->on('sites.owner', '=', DB::raw($user->id));
        })
```